# In which military branch did Ted Striker serve?

Tags: plot-explanation, airplane

In the comedy *Airplane!*, character Ted Striker has post-traumatic stress disorder after losing the rest of his squadron.  What military branch was he supposed to have served in?  Is it consistently portrayed throughout the movie?  Is it consistent with the white uniform he wears in the disco scene (as shown below)?

[image: Ted Striker]

Comment: Why do you have a continuity tag on this?  Do you think this uniform (for a US Navy Lieutenant, O2) is somehow inconsistent with something else?  If so I would include screenshots of those.

Comment: @iandotkelly: I do think there may be a continuity problem, as his mental hospital had a sign that it was an *army* mental hospital.

Comment: Yeah, that's not really continuity - which would be something like in the next shot there was a button missing or something.

Comment: No more inconsistent than playing propeller noise whenever the (jet) airplane is shown flying.

Comment: @iandotkelly "Plot continuity. Perhaps the most significant consistency errors are errors in plot continuity. Often called “plot holes,” these errors aren’t about visual continuity—rather, they’re conceptual inconsistencies ... For example, if a character says they’re an only child and then later tells a story about a sibling, that would be a plot continuity problem." https://www.masterclass.com/articles/how-to-maintain-continuity-in-film#how-to-identify-continuity-mistakes-in-film

Comment: @Acccumulation ... I stand corrected.

Comment: Which military branch?.... surely that's not important right now?

Comment: @DrSheldon — when something is described as an “Army mental hospital”, that means it is operated, commanded, and funded by that branch.  It does not mean that it only treats to members of that branch.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because I picked the wrong week to quit sniffing glue.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### Its inconsistently pictured but when mentioned it is the Air Force

His voiceover describes him as being in the Air Force

```
        STRIKER (v.o.)
I was in the Air Force, stationed in
Drambuie, on the Barbary Coast. I used to
hang out in the Magumba Bar.
```

Later when asked to fly the plane:

```
        STRIKER
Well, I flew single-engine fighters in the
Air Force, but this plane has four
engines. It's an entirely different kind
of flying...all together!!!
```

And when reporters ask who is flying the plane:

```
        REPORTER #2
Who's flying the plane?


        McCROSKEY
One of the passengers. But he's an
experienced air force pilot who flew
during the war so there's no cause for
alarm.
```

Yet he is wearing a Navy dress uniform in the Saturday Night Fever scene, and in an Army Mental Health Hospital in yet another.

This is almost certainly artistic license.  He shouldn't be wearing a dress uniform in a bar anyway - its just there so he can have white pants on and look the part for dancing during Saturday Night Fever song and the Air Force dress uniform is blue.  For the Hospital scene they want him painting the baby rescue scene, so set it in the Army.

Its only important to the plot that he is an ex-military pilot with PTSD.  It's not super important to the writers that this is in any way consistent.  The plane dogfight clips used appear to show World War II or Korean War era planes, which he is far too young to have fought in.  The writers and directors are just turning the character into a stereotype for the joke potential.

Comment: Considering what kind of film this is, I'd say it's less "artistic license" and more just "because it's funny".

Comment: @F1Krazy agreed, I lean heavily on that it's done because it's funny.  I'm surprised Striker didn't have a different branch's uniform each time, from navy to army to air force to coast guard, etc.

Comment: "It's an entirely different kind
of flying...all together!!!" It's an entirely different kind of flying.

Comment: It's an entirely different kind of flying!

Comment: "It's not super important to the writers that this is in any way consistent. " Reminder me that the audio you hear of the commercial jet airplane is actually that of a propeller plane the whole time. (and IIRC, it's the audio from *Zero Hour!*). So yeah, if a joke can be made, consistency be damned!

Comment: @BruceWayne Even better if they kept mixing up what country he was from - since the original Ted Stryker from *Zero Hour!* was Canadian and *Airplane!*'s Ted Striker is American.  But maybe that'd be too subtle.

Comment: @F1Krazy Isn't that what artistic license is all about? It means you do something inauthentic because it serves the artistic purposes of the movie. And in the case of a broad comedy, that purpose is to be funny.

Comment: I think @Barmar the point people are making isn't that they are glossing over the inconsistencies in order to allow another joke to happen - the inconsistencies themselves are meant to be funny for those that notice them.

Comment: @F1Krazy — TVTropes calls it “the [Rule of Funny](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny)”: Any violation of continuity, logic, physics, or common sense is permissible if the result gets enough of a laugh.

Answer (score 10):

While [the accepted answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/116858/18230) is indeed correct in the context of *Airplane!*, please note that the film wasn’t just a parody of the [*Airport* action/drama films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airport_(film_series)) of the 1970s, but also a direct parody of two earlier films: [*Flight into Danger*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_into_Danger) (1956) and [*Zero Hour!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_Hour!) (1957).

In the case of *Zero Hour!* the character of Ted Striker (*Airplane!*) is directly based on the character of Ted Stryker *Zero Hour!*.

And as per the Wikipedia description of the plot of that film:

> “During the closing days of the Second World War, six members of the Royal Canadian Air Force fighter squadron led by pilot Ted Stryker (Dana Andrews) are killed because of a command decision made by him. Years later, in civilian life in Winnipeg, Manitoba, a guilt-stricken Stryker goes through many jobs, and his marriage is in trouble.”

While PTSD is not explicitly stated, the description of Stryker’s World War II experience clearly implies that. And Stryker is clearly described as a member of the Royal Canadian Air Force here as well.

Yes, *Airplane!* parody of the *Airport* film series, but it was also a direct parody of the plots of *Zero Hour!* and *Flight into Danger*. As such, the role/character of “Ted Striker” is clearly based on the role/character of “Ted Stryker.” And Ted Striker is an Air Force pilot.

Comment: Yes, *Airplane!* follows most of the plot and dialogue of *Zero Hour!*, but in many ways they differ (e.g. B/W versus color, prop versus jet).  Had they strictly followed *Zero Hour!* (but Americanized), he would have been in the U.S. Army, as the U.S. "air force" in World War II was part of the army ("U.S. Army Air Force"); it did not become its own branch until 1947.